# Flutter: How to make TextView in Listview fill remaining space

Tags: android, flutter, flutter-layout

I need your help. I'm using a ListView that contains a Container with height of 100 and a `Textfield` with `maxlines` set to `null`.

`maxlines` are set to `null`, because the user should be able to write as many lines as he wants.

The `Textfield` and `Container` are nested in a `ListView` because they need to scroll together if the `Textfield` expands past the height of the screen.
So I'm basically trying to make some sort of note app. The `Container` is the header. The `Textfield` is the `textbody`.

The Problem:
When the user has not entered anything into the `Textfield`, the `Textfield` should fill the remaining space. So it should expand to the end of the screen like Expandable Widget does in a Row. How can I achieve that?

[image]

Comment: add some code of what you've done so far ... but also from what you're saying, trying setting a `minLines` value to that which will fill the entire screen

Comment: @mjhansen3 minLines works fine! Do you've any idea on how to calculate the minLines to fill exactly the remaining space?

Comment: at the moment, I do not know how to calculate the exact number that'll fit the remaining space.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This should accomplish what you're trying to do:

```
class MyPageBody extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return LayoutBuilder(
      builder: (context, constraint) {
        return SingleChildScrollView(
          child: ConstrainedBox(
            constraints: BoxConstraints(minHeight: constraint.maxHeight),
            child: IntrinsicHeight(
              child: Column(
                children: <Widget>[
                  Container(
                    height: 100,
                    alignment: Alignment.center,
                    color: Colors.green,
                    child: Text("Header"),
                  ),
                  Expanded(
                    child: TextField(
                      expands: true,
                      maxLines: null,
                      decoration: InputDecoration(
                          fillColor: Colors.blue[200], filled: true),
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
        );
      },
    );
  }
}
```

[image: One line of text (Still expands to fill visible space)]
[image: Multiple lines (Scrollable/stays below header and expands to fill visible space)]

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I'll try if it works for me later :)

Comment: I updated my question. It would be nice if you could take a quick look at it :)

Comment: The new part of your question is actually an entirely different question. For the integrity of the first question, would you mind deleting your updated portion? To get a tab bar that always stays at the bottom look into `BottomNavigationBar`. 
You will have three parts. 1. The appBar at the top, 2. The body (this is the part that scrolls). and 3. Your bottom Navigation bar

Comment: I can open a new topic/question for that. I'm already using a BottomNavigationBar. The problem is that I can't get the body to behave as I want.

Comment: I accepted your answer, because it solves my original question. I also opened a new Question with more explanation and code: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59993861/flutter-problems-with-bottomnavigationbar