# Flutter: Using Expandable Textfield with BottomNavigationBar

Tags: android, flutter, flutter-layout

I need some help with this layout :)

The Layout contains a `BottomNavigationBar`. The body consists of a `Container` at the top (which serves as some kind of header) and a `Textfield` below the `Container`. The `Textfield` should expand to fill the remaining space. As soon as the user enters enough lines so that the text doesn't fit on the screen, the whole body (`Textfield` and `Container`) should become `scrollable`.

So it's basically a note app with a `Header` (the `Container` part) and multiple `Tabs` for Note taking.

[image]

This is the solution so far:

```
  Scaffold buildBody(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(...),
      body: _buildScaffoldBody(),
      bottomNavigationBar: Column(
        mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
        children: [
          AnimatedCrossFade(
            firstChild: Material(
              color: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
              child: TabBar(
                controller: _tabController,
                tabs: _tabNames,
                onTap: (int) {
                 ...
                },
              ),
            ),
            secondChild: Container(),
            crossFadeState: _screen == 0
                            ? CrossFadeState.showFirst
                            : CrossFadeState.showSecond,
            duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 300),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

Widget _buildScaffoldBody() {
return LayoutBuilder(
      builder: (context, constraint) {
        return SingleChildScrollView(
          child: ConstrainedBox(
            constraints: BoxConstraints(minHeight: constraint.maxHeight),
            child: IntrinsicHeight(
              child: Column(
                children: <Widget>[
                  Container(
                    height: 100,
                    alignment: Alignment.center,
                    color: Colors.green,
                    child: Text("Header"),
                  ),
                 Expanded(              //This is probably the cause 
                    child:  TabBarView(    //of the exception
                        controller: _tabController,
                        children: <Widget>[
                          TextField(
                            expands: true,
                            maxLines: null,
                            decoration: InputDecoration(
                                fillColor: Colors.blue[200], filled: true),
                          ),
                          TextField(
                            expands: true,
                            maxLines: null,
                            decoration: InputDecoration(
                                fillColor: Colors.blue[200], filled: true),
                          ),
                          TextField(
                            expands: true,
                            maxLines: null,
                            decoration: InputDecoration(
                                fillColor: Colors.blue[200], filled: true),
                          ),
                        ]
                      )
                    )
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
        );
      },
    );
```

But it's throwing an exception.I tried replacing `Expanded` with a `Container` and hardcoding `height` and `width`. If I do so the exception is not thrown, but the `Textfield` is no longer `expandable` and  it doesn't scroll together with the `Header`. It only scrolls within the `Container` wrapping the `Textfield`.

```
The following assertion was thrown during performLayout():
I/flutter ( 8080): RenderViewport does not support returning intrinsic dimensions.
I/flutter ( 8080): Calculating the intrinsic dimensions would require instantiating every child of the viewport, which
I/flutter ( 8080): defeats the point of viewports being lazy.
I/flutter ( 8080): If you are merely trying to shrink-wrap the viewport in the main axis direction, consider a
I/flutter ( 8080): RenderShrinkWrappingViewport render object (ShrinkWrappingViewport widget), which achieves that
I/flutter ( 8080): effect without implementing the intrinsic dimension API.
I/flutter ( 8080): 
I/flutter ( 8080): The relevant error-causing widget was:
I/flutter ( 8080):   IntrinsicHeight
```

Answer (score 0):

You just have some stuff misplaced. Try as much as you can to break apart your code into re-usable widgets. It helps to keep everything more organized.

Also, as a general rule, when you're trying to implement something commonly needed, chances are there will be a widget built for it already. In this case, you don't need to mess with the `AnimatedCrossFade` etc... It's all built into the `TabBarView`.

```
void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: TabBarScaffold(),
    );
  }
}

class TabBarScaffold extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new MaterialApp(
      color: Colors.yellow,
      home: DefaultTabController(
        length: 3,
        child: new Scaffold(
          body: MyPages(),
          bottomNavigationBar: MyTabs(),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class MyTabs extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return TabBar(
      tabs: [
        Tab(
          child: Text("Tab 1"),
        ),
        Tab(
          child: Text("Tab 2"),
        ),
        Tab(
          child: Text("Tab 3"),
        ),
      ],
      labelColor: Colors.blue,
      unselectedLabelColor: Colors.black,
      indicatorSize: TabBarIndicatorSize.label,
      indicatorPadding: EdgeInsets.all(5.0),
      indicatorColor: Colors.red,
    );
  }
}

class MyPages extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return TabBarView(
      children: [
        MyPageBody(
          textBackgroundColor: Colors.blue[200],
        ),
        MyPageBody(
          textBackgroundColor: Colors.green[200],
        ),
        MyPageBody(
          textBackgroundColor: Colors.red[200],
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}

class MyPageBody extends StatelessWidget {
  final Color textBackgroundColor;
  MyPageBody({this.textBackgroundColor});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return LayoutBuilder(
      builder: (context, constraint) {
        return SingleChildScrollView(
          child: ConstrainedBox(
            constraints: BoxConstraints(minHeight: constraint.maxHeight),
            child: IntrinsicHeight(
              child: Column(
                children: <Widget>[
                  Container(
                    height: 100,
                    alignment: Alignment.center,
                    color: Colors.green,
                    child: Text("Header"),
                  ),
                  Expanded(
                    child: TextField(
                      expands: true,
                      maxLines: null,
                      decoration: InputDecoration(
                          fillColor: textBackgroundColor, filled: true),
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
        );
      },
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: 1.) Im using AnimatedCrossfade etc for a reason. The standard NavigationBar didn't work for me, because I need a dynamic and scrollable BottomNavigatiomBar. I can't find the stackoverflow post where I got it from...  But the BottomNavigation is working fine as aspected.

Comment: 2.) The Container, which contains the Header shouldn't be part of the TabBarBody, because it should stay fixed when swiping through the tabs. So it needs to be outside of the TabBarBody. But still thanks for trying to help :)

Comment: Or in other words, if you start scrolling, the Container (Header) and Tab should behave as one Page -> Container and Tab scroll together. If you swipe right or left, the Container and Tab/TabBarBody should behave seperate -> The Container stays fixed while the Tab/TabBarBody moves right or left.